# How to use jQuery to tell if the user can scroll or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple quiz application that displays a question and 4 multiple choice answers.

Sometimes the text for the questions and answers can't fit on one page and the user must scroll down to view it. If that is the case I would like to display a message at the top of the screen for the user, to indicate that there are more options further down.

However, if all of the answers are on screen I would not like to show this warning.

I'm not a `jQuery/javascript` expert. From what I've seen there are plenty of answers for checking if a user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, but I don't think that specifically helps me.

Answer (score 1):

If `window.height` < `document.height` then the user can scroll vertically. So given your requirements, you'd need to check those properties on the `resize` event of the window and show the message if needed. Something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#scrollWarningElement').toggle($(this).height() < $(document).height());
}).resize(); // call on load too
```